# XMLHttpRequest function return data only in the last call

Tags: javascript, post, request, xmlhttprequest

my problem is...

I made a javascript function to using XMLHttpRequest get some data from my database, using POST method, if i use this function only one time, this works how i want, but i need to call this function more than 1 time in my project and when i call 2 or more times only last request give me some data, the firsts only show the body of POST method but doesn't return data, so the question is...

How can i make this function works every time i call?

And if you guys can tell me why this is happening now i would be grateful too

I put logs in my function to see what's happening and my body for POST method request is there, every single time, but only last function gets a returned data, other even return something...

My function:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getListOfProducts(id, paramsCat, paramsSubcat, insertCheckout) {
  var params1 = {
    id_categoria: paramsCat,
    id_subcategoria: paramsSubcat,
    slug: "",
  };
  console.log(params1);

  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log("Loaded");
    var parse = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    var products = parse.results;
    console.log(products);
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params1));
}
```

Comment: why not use fetch api.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: so you call `getListOfProducts` multiple times? and only the last one works? perhaps the others are failing ... and an `xhr.onerror` handler and log any errors you get

Comment: Thanks for the answer, fetch is really a good option, i will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, You can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). In existing code, Create XMLHttpRequest object every time you call getListOfProducts. Since you have same instance of xhr. So this won't work on the next call.

```
function getListOfProducts(id, paramsCat, paramsSubcat, insertCheckout) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //... rest of the code
}
```

**Similar code in fetch:**

```
function getListOfProducts(id, paramsCat, paramsSubcat, insertCheckout) {
  var params1 = {
    id_categoria: paramsCat,
    id_subcategoria: paramsSubcat,
    slug: "",
  };
  fetch({
    url: url,
    body: JSON.stringify(params1),
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      var products = res.results;
      console.log(products);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked really well, i put my var xhr inside the function and it worked... Thank you! :)